# Matching regex pattern where there is \n\r between starting and ending pattern

Tags: python, regex

- The red underscore is the desired string I want to match
- I would like to match all strings (including \n) between the the two string provided in the example
- However, in the first example, where there is a newline, I can't get anything to match
- In the second example, the regex expression works. It matches the string highlighted in Green because it resides on a single line
- Not sure if there is a notation I need to include for \n\r to be part of the pattern to match

[image]

Comment: The dot doesn't match newlines. One way to match any character is `[\s\S\]`.

Comment: expression "This([\s\S]*)match"...matches to the second "match" in the string. How do I limit to the first occurrence of "match"?

Comment: try this way: "this([\s\S]*?)match"

Comment: There should be s flag to ignore newlines.

Comment: Thanks team. The following "This([\s\S]*?)match" did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
output = re.search('This(.*?)\n\n(.*?)match', text)
>>> output.group(1)
'is a multiline expression'
>>> output.group(2)
'I would like to '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one aswell:

```
output = re.search(r"This ([\S.]+) match", text).group(1).replace(r'\n','')
```

That will find the entire thing as one group then remove the new lines.